# SQL Clickhouse update multiple values based on CASE condition

Tags: sql, sql-update, clickhouse

I want to update some values in table with new values based names in column "name". I want do it
on the predefined time range. But when i run my query it's looks like WHEN clause is not working properly , because i just receive an Read timeout from DataBase.

When i use second query it's looks like all is ok. So could please someone help me with my first query? I need to update multiple values for predefined delta value for some of "name's" in predefined time range?
I use clickhouse db.  Thanks in advan

First query:

```
UPDATE stage.log  
SET value = 
(CASE WHEN name='banana'  THEN value-(-0.5)
      WHEN name='apple' THEN value - (-0.20001)
END)
WHERE time >= '2023-07-06 10:00:00'
AND   time <= '2023-07-06 10:00:07'
AND bt_run_no = 0
AND  name   in ('banana','apple')
```

Second query:

```
UPDATE value = value - (-0.20001)
WHERE   time >= '2023-07-06 10:00:00'
  AND   time <= '2023-07-06 10:00:07'
  AND name = 'apple'
```

exaple of existing data in table:

```
time                    name    value
----------------------------------------
2023-07-06 10:00:00.001 apple   0.06263
2023-07-06 10:00:01.051 banana  0.06335
2023-07-06 10:00:01.651 orange  0.06332
2023-07-06 10:00:01.690 orange  0.06331
2023-07-06 10:00:02.772 apple   0.0626
2023-07-06 10:00:03.002 apple   0.06261
2023-07-06 10:00:03.111 banana  0.06262
2023-07-06 10:00:03.830 orange  0.06302
2023-07-06 10:00:03.891 orange  0.06301
2023-07-06 10:00:04.330 orange  0.06331
2023-07-06 10:00:05.311 orange  0.06335
2023-07-06 10:00:05.801 apple   0.06258
2023-07-06 10:00:05.951 apple   0.06259
2023-07-06 10:00:06.091 apple   0.0626
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
UPDATE stage.log  
SET value = CASE 
    WHEN name='banana' THEN value-(-0.5)
    WHEN name='apple' THEN value-(-0.20001)
END
FROM [db_name].[dbo].[table]
WHERE time >= '2023-07-06 10:00:00' 
AND time <= '2023-07-06 10:00:07'
AND bt_run_no = 0
AND name in ('banana','apple')
```

Comment: SQL Error [62] [07000]: Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 191 ('FROM') (line 5, col 1): FROM stage.log
WHERE  time >= '2023-07-06 10:00:00' 
AND  time <= '2023-07-06 10:00:07'
AND bt_run_no = 0
AND name in . Expected one of: OR, AND, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN, LIKE, ILIKE, NOT LIKE, NOT ILIKE, REGEXP, IN, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN, GLOBAL NOT IN, MOD, DIV, IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, token, Comma, IN PARTITION, WHERE. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 23.3.2.37 (official build))

Comment: @ditrauth hi! Please change your table name 'log' to other names like 'log1' and try again

Comment: here is only one table - .log

Comment: @ditrauth I know, but your table name 'log' have names of SQL functions or types, that's why I suggested you to change the table name, it might work afterwards.

Comment: no, it's just an example. i have different table name in real data